# Add a vector to a position

Tags: math, 2d

I have an object in 2D space whose position is (A, B) and which has an orientation (between 0 and 360).
I have a distance, say D.
I would like to add D to the object's position, in the direction that the object is looking toward.

Mathematically, how would I go about doing that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result would be:

(X,Y) = (A,B) + D*(cos(O),sin(O))

*Edit:* The vector equation is equivalent to:

X = A + D*cos(O)

Y = B + D*sin(O)

Comment: Thanks, however could you explain separately how to get X and and how to get Y? thank you. I am not at all knowledgeable of these concepts.

Comment: These kinds of problems are best expressed using vectors. I would recommend you look them up, it's much more convenient than manipulating the coordinates directly.

Comment: Thanks, but what I am looking for is the coordinates of the object after I have moved it forward by the D distance. Which I guess the formula you gave me allows to calculate, but I don't know what (A, B) added to something else means, or what D multiplied by (A, B) means.
Hence I would be very thankful if you could detail the formula by explaining how each value will be manipulated. Thank you. 

To explain, I know what D * A means for example. But I don't know what D * (A,B) means.

Comment: Actually, this formula doesn't seem to take into the account the direction of movement. Is this correct? The object has an orientation, and I would like to move it in the direction it's looking towards.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the equations to take into account the orientation.