# Adding a specific distance to X,Y coordinates in a specific direction

Tags: math, 2d, coordinates

I have an object in 2D space whose position is (A, B). This object also has an orientation (between 0 and 360). I have a value, say D. I would like to add D to the object's position (to move the object 'forward' by a length of D), in the direction that the object is looking towards.

Mathematically, how would I go about doing that? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683302/add-a-vector-to-a-position

Answer (score 1):

```
A+= D * cos(angle);
B+= D * sin(angle);
```